# VLAN aware bridging for KVM hypervisor on debian 10 (buster) and later

Tags: debian, vlan, bridge

I am setting up a new KVM hypervisor and the VMs will need to connect to several VLANS (one VLAN per VM). However I can't find good documentation or instructions on how to configure the hypervisor or the VMs - perhaps because VLAN filtering and VLAN aware bridges are still new (from 2018 i think).

So I look for examples and best practices on setup and maintenance. Do I need special packages? Bonus points for Ansible receipts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [instructions](http://wiki.hoeft-online.de/VLAN_for_virtual_machines#linux_bridge_with_libvirt_hook_scripts) on how to use the new VLAN aware bridges for setup of VMs, but people who are familiar with the libvirt world are not fond of this approach. They promote usage of openvswitch for the handling of VLANs instead.

Also I spend some time trying to create a setup like described in [1](http://wiki.hoeft-online.de/VLAN_for_virtual_machines#linux_bridge_with_libvirt_hook_scripts), and failed when trying to connect the bridge to the VMs' interfaces, despite time and effort and some help from libvirt folks.

So the right answer seems to be "Dont do that" for now. My own working solution with Open VSwitch is described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033473/why-does-my-ethernet-interface-not-get-added-to-my-openvswitch-bridge-on-startup).